# How can I redirect to a special page when I have parameters in url slashes?

Tags: javascript, html, web

For example, I want the users to be able to go to a tour using a link like this:

```
page.com/tour/name
```

How can I make it, like redirecting to tour.html and then loading there the info using the name parameter in the URL? Using JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lines in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^tour/([^/]+).php /page.php?search=$1 [NC]
```